# Error de sintaxis en controlador Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Me salen los campos nulos, porque no es un "input" lo que estoy recibiendo, si no un "option" pero no se como declarar para que agarre el valor del option para mi registro.

Formulario:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{url('/orderSet')}}" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Empleado:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <select class="form-control">
         @foreach($emp as $e)
             //Dato enviado: <option name="Employee" value="{{$e->id}}">{{$e->Name}}</option>
@endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function orderSet(Request $data){
    $order= new Order();
    $order->idAdmin="1";
    $order->idEmployee=$data->input('Employee');//datoRecibido(en blanco porque no es un input)
    $order->idClient=$data->input('Client');
    $order->idServices=$data->input('Service');
    $order->Description=$data->input('Password');
    $order->Status='1';
    $order->save();
    return Redirect('/order');
}
```

Comment: ¿qué es lo que recibes y qué es lo que esperas? Necesitamos más información y más código, probablemente necesitemos el código de la vista del formulario.

Comment: Ya agregué el formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad name debe ir en la etiqueta `<select>` y no en `<option>`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Employee">
  @foreach($emp as $e)
    <option value="{{$e->id}}">{{$e->Name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: ........Gracias!